# Struggling with camera border in the viewport

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I've tried changing the resolution but the problem isn't resolved even on the default resolution. The camera is stuck like this

[image]

I'm trying to revert it back to this (highlighted border)

[image]

Comment: What happens if you press 0 (zero) on the numpad?

Comment: @John Eason: Blender will then exit the Camera Perspective, which is currently already active (see info text in the upper left corner of image 1)

Comment: That just exits/enters the camera view but the boarder in the viewport remains in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

You have **Lock Camera To View** enabled. This will move the Camera Object according to your 3D view navigation.

A very useful feature, being able to "move around" while looking through the Lens... But you might want to turn it off for a second, so you can get the Cam back to the screen center by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Middle Mouse</kbd> for panning the view.

[image]

Comment: Loading the blend file in a new session , with "load ui " unchecked , seemed to fix the problem

Comment: For sure, a hard reset can also help. :-) However, should you someday, somehow, end up in that same situation again, please remember there's is a good reason and a really simple solution for the 'border behavior' (which i tried to point out concisely in my answer). Pity you didn't give it a go...

Comment: Thanks I do appreciate your help